# How to obtain a long lasting Facebook Access Token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Main objective: How can I get an access token with unlimited validity for a facebook app?

**Background information**

We have a FB app called MyApp with the following set up:

- MyApp is authorized to interact with our facebook app
- MyApp has access rights to manage our pages (manage_pages)
- MyApp has access to Insights (read_insights)

Our goal is to extract the Insights data automatically, e.g. once every night.

**Attempt with oauth generated app token**

1. Get APP_ACCESS_TOKEN belonging to MyAPP

   graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

   example of retireved token: 328467452729456598|Wn2Gt69Ofg5ySdOGa3TsP2p4R
2. Use APP_ACCESS_TOKEN to get PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN for each page
   graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
3. Use PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN to get the page’s Insights data:
   graph.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_ID/insights?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN

My problem is that the APP_ACCESS_TOKEN I get from step 1 seems to be missing the user part of the token, resulting in the following error when running step 2:

```
 "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
 "type": "OAuthException",
 "code": 2500
```

**Attempt with token retrieved from Graph Explorer API token**

If I use the APP_ACCESS_TOKEN gained through the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer),  I get a token with the user part that is significantly longer.
If I use this token in step 2 and 3, I get correct data, but all tokens are only valid for 2 hours, and subsequently I cannot use this for automated retrieval of insights data.

**Attempt with exchanging short lived token for long lived token**

Following the steps outlined in this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#page_access_token, I tried to exchange a short lived token for a longer lived one.

If I use try to exchange the token obtained from the oauth process, I get the error:

```
  "message": "No user access token specified",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 1
```

If I use the token obtained manually from the Graph explorer in the exchange method, I can get the other steps to work as well, but for how long does this new token last? If the token expires after x days or after the some other event, I would still be faced with the issue of obtaining the initial token programatically (as opposed to manually every from the Graph Explorer).

So does anyone know how I can get a long-lived, automatically retrieved token to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a _user_ access token to query `/me/accounts`, not an app access token.

Answer (score 2):

This shell script attempts to help generate access tokens:

https://github.com/dncohen/fb_token

Answer (score -1):

In step 2, you must use the user's `access_token` to access the `/accounts` API endpoint. You cannot use the App Access Token here.

What you should do is:

1. Get the user's access token from Facebook
2. Exchange the access_token for a long-lived token
3. Call `/accounts` to get a long-live page access token
4. Access page insights using the long-lived token until it expires
5. Repeat steps 1-4.

Comment: Do you mean the App's [User token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/)? If so, is there some way to get this programmatically?

(I am trying with User acces

Comment: I said App `access_token` not "user token". Follow my instructions above to get what you need programmatically. In step (3), I give you the API call to get the access_token for the page. Everything must be done using the user's `access_token`

Comment: See the documentation on getting a long-lived access token here: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: this link is now broken

Comment: Seeing as this was answered over 5 years ago, it's not surprising. The new documentation for long-lived tokens can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing